# Multiple conditions with numpy where (np.where)

Tags: python, numpy, conditional-statements

I am trying to assign a score of either `1`, `-1` or `0`, depending on a stocks daily move. If it is up I assign `1`, down I assign `-1` and unchanged I assign `0`. I have stumbled across the function `np.where`, but it only allows for two possible conditions, so in my example I can only assign `1` or `-1`.

So my code currently would be:

`df['Score'] = np.where(df['Stock_dly_PX'].diff(1) > 0, 1, -1)`

But this leaves me with any unchanged days as being assigned a `-1`, and I want unchanged days to be assigned a `0`.

Any help greatly appreciated, cheers.

Comment: `np.select` is its analogous for multiple conditions

Comment: Thanks for pointing that thread out mate, works perfectly, cheers